# QGIS coordinates not displaying correctly

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer, grids-graticules

Making my first Print in QGIS, and for some reason the coordinates are all over the place (see image). Does anyone know what would be causing this?

All of my settings seem quite standard, I will post these as well. This area should be bounded by a rectangle of just a few minutes in span.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the map properties window, there should be a button to set the extent of the print to the map or data view. It could be that this has defaulted to a 0,0 origin and so shows the extent from 0,0 as opposed to the bounding box of your data.

Comment: Have you tried changing your map units to `m`? EPSG6345 is a CRS based on `m`, thus the notation with `degree` is clearly wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you have selected a correct CRS - one valid in the area you map?

Comment: You need to scroll down to the labeling part of your grid. There you may choose the correct display of your coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I am not sure of the version of QGIS you are running, but this should apply to most QGIS 3.x versions.

When you add a map to the layout, you can access the map item properties.
From the screenshot provided, you seem to be accessing the "Map Grid Properties".

The item properties for your map will have icons under the map name - default is "Map 1".
These icons may look different depending on version, but in 3.10 they are a "refresh", boxes with arrows and some page extent controllers.

Click on the "Set Map Extent to Match Canvas Extent" button, this will change the map to the extent of your canvas.

Make sure the canvas is at an extent you feel you can use, you can then tweak it as you go.

Answer (score 1):

All,
After watching several videos / learning more about the process for adding grids on the map, I realized I was using the wrong CRS as Erik pointed out. I switched to EPSG6345 and everything started working properly. Thank you all!